# Error while installing sitecore 10.2 :"Package 'SqlServer' failed to be installed because: End of Central Directory record could not be found'

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework, sitecore-install-assistant

Please find the error log details:

```
The script 'Invoke-RemoveSqlDatabaseTask.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: SqlServer.
                      ************************************
                           Sitecore Install Framework
                                 Version - 2.3.0
                      ************************************


WorkingDirectory       : ..\Downloads\Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 
                         1.4.0-r5)
WhatIf                 : False
Verbose                : SilentlyContinue
Configuration          : ..\Downloads\Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 
                         1.4.0-r5)\Prerequisites.json
Debug                  : SilentlyContinue
AutoRegisterExtensions : False
WarningAction          : Continue
ErrorAction            : Stop
InformationAction      : Continue





[-- DownloadVisualC++2015x86 [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[--------- InstallC++2015x86 [Skipped] : StartProcess ------------------------]

[-- DownloadVisualC++2015x64 [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[--------- InstallC++2015x64 [Skipped] : StartProcess ------------------------]

[--------------------- SQLServerModule : InstallModule -----------------------]
Package 'SqlServer' failed to be installed because: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
[TIME] 00:08:05
Package 'SqlServer' failed to be installed because: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
```

Comment: Is it possible you are low on disk space?

Comment: No Dean. we have enough disk space..I guess that  there might be a security error. but dont know what we have to do.

Comment: did you know what is the reason to get the security error? we have admin access to our system.. still we are getting security error..

Answer (score 0):

The error states that it is not able to install the package and there can be some possible reason for this.

- It can be possible the firewall restrictions are in place and don't let it download or install the required package.
- The zip files are corrupted. Usually, the easiest way to resolve it is to simply re-download the file if it was corrupted, or if the file was incomplete.
- Drive may cause permission issues unless you have granted access in the folder's properties in file explorer.

Another way you can try to install it on another machine to identify that it is actually because of a security farewell issue. If other people in your organization are also getting the same issue then it is a security firewall issue and you need to check with your IT team to resolve it.

Hope this will help you to identify the issue.